# Angular ng-show not animating on hide

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, animation

I have Angular animation working by hovering over this li, it animates on show of the buttonHolder class **but not on mouseleave.** It just disappears.

```
<li class='notifyItem' ng-repeat="product in notify.notifications" ng-mouseenter="notify.showButtons(product)" ng-mouseleave="notify.showButtons(product)">
```

here is the function:

```
this.showButtons = function(idx) {

            idx.buttonShow = !idx.buttonShow;
        };
```

Here is the button that is animated:

```
<button ng-show='product.buttonShow' class='buttonHolder caseButton btn-mini'>Create Case</button>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.buttonHolder.ng-hide-remove {
height: 0;
transition: height .1s;}

.buttonHolder.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
height: 25px;}
```

Just for reference I got the info about animations from: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html

Comment: Can you come up with a fiddle for the issue

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I found this workaround:    `.buttonHolder.ng-hide-add {
    height: 25px;
    transition: height .08s;
}`
    `.buttonHolder.ng-hide-add-active {
    height: 0;
} `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up adding to make it work:

```
.buttonHolder.ng-hide-add { height: 25px; transition: height .08s; }  
.buttonHolder.ng-hide-add-active { height: 0; }
```

It appears that both the ng-hide and ng-show are used when I use just ng-show. So both sets of classes are needed to give the animation both ways.